# Azure website virtual drive and scaling

Tags: azure, virtualization, mappeddrive

My current understanding of Azure for websites is that it is using a virtual drive which allows a website to save files to the file system in the same way a classic server setup would do.

The question is however if this virtual drive is mirrored across different locations and what happens if the website instance scales. Is the drive scales as well? Are all files saved to that drive replicated across instances? Are all instances reading from the same drive?

While it is quite obvious that it should do some of the above as cloud hosting, I cannot find any documentation on the same.

Any links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Web Sites deep dive](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Internals-with-Nir-Mashkowski) by Nir Mashkowski (from the Web Sites team). He walks through the architecture, including how the local disk is backed by an Azure blob and exposed as an SMB share. This means all of your Web Site instances are using "local disk" that's actually blob-backed and the same for each instance. You'll see this in the architecture starting around the 20:00 mark on the video.

As far as scaling: I'm not quite sure what you're referring to, specifically.